# How to evaluate an expression in for loop using Python?

Tags: python

I want to evaluate an expression inside for loop. I am doing:

```
for i in range(0,255):
    Q[i+1,1] = (np.floor_divide(i, q) * q + q/2)
```

but this returns an error saying

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size is 256x1 but still you have to index with starting at 0. So you need `Q[i,0]`

Comment: Hey, I am stuck at one last point, please if you can help. The code is as follows:

Comment: y = np.zeros(img.size, dtype = "uint8")

for i in range(1,height+1):
    for j in range(1,width+1):
        y[i,j] = Q(img[i,j]+1)

Comment: I'm on the phone so cannot test but probably you need `img.shape`.

Comment: I am trying both  "img.size" and  "img.shape". I think the problem is in the statement:     y[i,j] = Q[img[i,j] + 1]      If you can just check this statement and tell if anything is wrong with this. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 0):

*python* (and *numpy*) uses [zero-based indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), so the first position is 0. You should change your loop to:

```
for i in range(0,255):
    Q[i,0] = (np.floor_divide(i, q) * q + q/2)
#  ---^-^---
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help but now I have an error in this part.                 y = np.zeros(img.size, dtype = "uint8")

for i in range(1,height+1):
    for j in range(1,width+1):
        y[i,j] = Q(img[i,j]+1)